# Two guns not displayed, even though twin holster crafted

Tags: ps3, assassins-creed-3

I've crafted a twin holster and the two guns are not displayed.

The second holster is there but the gun isn't displayed and even the Gun icon on the HUD shows 2 fragments (as I've equipped the gun, which has 2 barrels).

I've also patched the game although I don't recall the version number.

How do I see both guns?

Comment: Wish I had this issue! Still trying to find the crafts people for the estate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try going to the mansion or a store and equipping/buying a different gun (and then switching back if you want). This fixed that issue for me, although occasionally I'll end up with two different guns somehow and I'll constantly get a message about how I've "acquired one weapon" or some such every time a map loads. :(

Comment: Exactly. For a short amount of time, that is until I get to the loading screen, I have the weapon of my choice but after the load screen, what you've said happens and I end up with 2 different firearms - double flintock and pitcairn in my case.

Comment: It seems to be very buggy, yeah :\